# LINQ Query Help

Tags: linq

I have the following Linq query:

```
from workItem in WorkItem
    join workItemHistory in WorkItemHistory on workItem equals workItemHistory.WorkItem
    join ivSweepHistory in IVSweepHistory on workItemHistory equals ivSweepHistory.WorkItemHistory
    where workItem.SerialNumber == "080106081985"
    orderby ivSweepHistory.ReadTime descending
select ivSweepHistory
```

As is, this works great. However, I want to modify this so that I only retrieve the first row instead of all rows. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: For those curious between the difference between `.First` (and `.FirstOrDefault`) and `.Take(x)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq/1024577#1024577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose it in Take.

```
(from workItem in WorkItem
    join workItemHistory in WorkItemHistory on workItem equals workItemHistory.WorkItem
    join ivSweepHistory in IVSweepHistory on workItemHistory equals ivSweepHistory.WorkItemHistory
    where workItem.SerialNumber == "080106081985"
    orderby ivSweepHistory.ReadTime descending
select ivSweepHistory)Take(1)
```

Comment: All answers were good. Your's was the closest to what I was asking for.

Answer (score 6):

```
var item = (from workItem in WorkItem 
            join workItemHistory in WorkItemHistory on workItem equals workItemHistory.WorkItem 
            join ivSweepHistory in IVSweepHistory on workItemHistory equals ivSweepHistory.WorkItemHistory 
            where workItem.SerialNumber == "080106081985" 
            orderby ivSweepHistory.ReadTime descending 
            select ivSweepHistory).first();
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) method:

```
var query = // your query;
var result = query.First();
```

If there's a possibility of no results being returned use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) instead to avoid an exception from being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

```
var allResults = from workItem in WorkItem
    join workItemHistory in WorkItemHistory on workItem 
        equals workItemHistory.WorkItem
    join ivSweepHistory in IVSweepHistory on workItemHistory 
        equals ivSweepHistory.WorkItemHistory
    where workItem.SerialNumber == "080106081985"
    orderby ivSweepHistory.ReadTime descending
select ivSweepHistory

var first = allResults.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
(from workItem in WorkItem
    join workItemHistory in WorkItemHistory on workItem 
        equals workItemHistory.WorkItem
    join ivSweepHistory in IVSweepHistory on workItemHistory 
        equals ivSweepHistory.WorkItemHistory
    where workItem.SerialNumber == "080106081985"
    orderby ivSweepHistory.ReadTime descending
select ivSweepHistory).FirstOrDefault();
```

You could also use `First()`, but if the query fails to return any results, `First()` will throw an Exception whereas `FirstOrDefault()` will handle the condition gracefully.