# left string function in C#

Tags: c#, string

What's the best way to return the first word of a string in C#?

Basically if the string is `"hello world"`, I need to get `"hello"`.

Thanks

Comment: Is space the only character you want to seperate words? What about tab, newline, and carriage return?

Comment: extending cwap's comment: what about punctuations? "hello, world"?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Substring` and `IndexOf`.

```
var s = "Hello World";
var firstWord = s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(" "));
```

However, this will not give the expected word if the input string only has one word, so a special case is needed.

```
var s = "Hello";
var firstWord = s.IndexOf(" ") > -1 
                  ? s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(" "))
                  : s;
```

Comment: I would add a special case for if the string contains only one word, e.g. if **IndexOf** returns -1.

Answer (score 57):

You can try:

```
string s = "Hello World";
string firstWord = s.Split(' ').First();
```

[Ohad Schneider's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67824/ohad-schneider) comment is right, so you can simply ask for the `First()` element as there will always be at least one element.

For further info on whether to use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` you can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq)

Comment: Slight improvement: use the overload for `String.Split` that takes a maximum splits count as you don't care about all but the first section.

Comment: You don't need `FirstOrDefault`, there will always be at least one element so you can just write `First` (even if there's no space you'll get the entire string).

Comment: Your solution is correct, there's no need to "try".

Comment: Why involve Linq at all? If there will always be an element and you are using first, just access it via the indexer: `string firstWord = s.Split(' ')[0];`

Comment: Notice that the maximum split parts (if used) should be 2 and not 1: theString.Split(new char []{ ' ', '\t'}, 2).First();

Answer (score 8):

One way is to look for a space in the string, and use the position of the space to get the first word:

```
int index = s.IndexOf(' ');
if (index != -1) {
  s = s.Substring(0, index);
}
```

Another way is to use a regular expression to look for a word boundary:

```
s = Regex.Match(s, @"(.+?)\b").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

The [answer of Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607310/left-string-function-in-c/3607316#3607316) is the most efficient if you want to split only on spaces. But, just for the sake of variety, here's another version:

```
var  FirstWord = "Hello World".Split(null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
```

As a bonus this will also recognize [all kinds of exotic whitespace characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) and will ignore multiple consecutive whitespace characters (in effect it will trim the leading/trailing whitespace from the result).

Note that it will count symbols as letters too, so if your string is `Hello, world!`, it will return `Hello,`. If you don't need that, then pass an array of delimiter characters in the first parameter.

But if you want it to be 100% foolproof in every language of the world, then it's going to get tough...

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly stolen from the msdn site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
string words = "This is a list of words, with: a bit of punctuation" +
    "\tand a tab character.";

string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });

if( split.Length > 0 )
{
    return split[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handles the various different whitespace characters, empty string and string of single word.

```
private static string FirstWord(string text)
{
    if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int index = 0; index < text.Length; index += 1)
    {
        char ch = text[index];
        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch)) break;

        builder.Append(ch);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `Split` for all the string, **Limit your Split to count of 2**. Use the overload which takes count as parameter as well. Use [String.Split Method (Char[], Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string str = "hello world";
string firstWord = str.Split(new[]{' '} , 2).First();
```

`Split` will always return an array with at least one element so either `.[0]` or `First` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
string words = "hello world";
string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {' '});
if(split.Length >0){
 string first = split[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this function in my code. It provides an option to either uppercase the first word or every single word.

```
        public static string FirstCharToUpper(string text, bool firstWordOnly = true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return text;
            }
            else
            {
                if (firstWordOnly)
                {
                    string[] words = text.Split(' ');
                    string firstWord = words.First();
                    firstWord = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(firstWord.ToLower());
                    words[0] = firstWord;
                    return string.Join(" ", words);
                }
                else
                {
                    return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Exc(ex);
            return text;
        }
    }
```