# Linq to SQL 'Select Where' Problem (WPF C# 4.0)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I used linq to sql many times its work correctly but today something wrong

this is code which must select password from users table.
I call this method tell wright... result is not password please see picture.

```
public void GetPassword(int id) 
    {
        using (HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext())
        {
            _CurrentPassword = (from p in db.users
                                    where p.id == _CurrentID
                                    select p.password).ToString();
        }
    }
```

this how i use this method

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select User");
        }
        else if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Only One User");
        }
        else
        {
            _CurrentID = Convert.ToInt32(listView1.SelectedValue);
            GetPassword(_CurrentID);

            if (PasswordBox.Password == _CurrentPassword)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You r in");
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Password Is incorrect, please try again");
                MessageBox.Show(_CurrentPassword);
            }

        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `SingleOrDefault` call or a call to `Single`, `First` or `FirstOrDefault`:

```
_CurrentPassword = (from p in db.users
                    where p.id == _CurrentID
                    select p.password).Single().ToString();
```

Explanation: Your query returns an `IEnumerable<string>` even if there is only one item returned. You first need to get that item, before you can make a sensible call to `ToString()`. BTW: I think the call to `ToString()` is not needed, because `p.password` already should be a string.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're doing `ToString()` on the LINQ expression, not the password.  Can you try removing `.ToString()` in `GetPassword`?

Also, as someone else pointed out, you need to select a single value from the enumerable -- `SingleOrDefault()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the expression:

```
from p in db.users
  where p.id == _CurrentID
  select p.password
```

is `IQueryable<string>`, not `string` (assuming `p.password` is a `string`). Use `.First()` or other method to just select a single element from the queryable collection.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is to convert what is inside the linq query to a string, not the result of the query.You can

try

```
_CurrentPassword = (from p in db.users 
                    where p.id == _CurrentID 
                    select p.password).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

or

```
_CurrentPassword = (from p in db.users 
                    where p.id == _CurrentID 
                    select p.password).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

Please refer to these questions and answers to choose between `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`.

[When to use .First and when to use .FirstOrDefault with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq)

and

[LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)