# Why use First instead of FirstOrDefault in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use .First and when to use .FirstOrDefault with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq)

What is the point of using the `First` operator in LINQ, when you could use the `FirstOrDefault` operator instead?

```
var q = results.First(); // Error if empty
```

Comment: I could see a close for a duplicate, but ... "not constructive"? :( Although, I think the question could use clarification as to *why* `First` (with Error-if-empty) is thought to be less ideal than `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To respond directly to your specific question (why use `First` if you can always use `FirstOrDefault`), there are instances where you cannot use `FirstOrDefault`, because it loses information! The "default value" is likely a valid element type in the source list. You have no way to distinguish between the first element in the enumeration being null/default vs. there being no elements in the list unless you use `First` or first check if there are `Any` elements, which requires double-enumeration.

This is especially true for value-typed enumerables, such as `int[]`. `default(int)` is `0`, which is also most likely a valid value of the array.

In general, the two methods represent different logical flows. `First` would be used if not having any elements is "exceptional" (an error), which then want to handle out-of-band in your application. In this scenario, you "expect" to have at least one element. `FirstOrDefault` returns null on an empty set, which means you need to do additional processing with the returned value. This is similar logic to the `Parse` vs `TryParse` methods on `int`/`double`/etc. In fact, your question in some ways leads itself to the more general question of why to ever use exceptions.

Since `First` throws an exception, it lends itself to all of the code-reuse opportunities that exceptions provide. For example, you could do:

```
try
{
    x = arr1.First();
    y = arr2.First();
    z = arr3.First();
}
catch
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To explicitly force an exception to get raised versus performing a `null` check.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same discussion as `Int32.Parse` vs. `Int32.TryParse`. The former throws an exception in case of failure, the latter returns false and the program continues smoothly...