# getting first element from nhibernate fetch collection

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have one entity which besides other information holds many images. This is one 2 many. 
In situation where I need to load just first from that collection to slow loading I have following query which retrieve collection of images.

```
 List<Entity> data = session.Query<Entity>()
          .Fetch(x=>x.Photos)//here I need only first element
          .Fetch(x=>x.Features)
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` method of th linq wiil do task for you

```
List<Entity> data = session.Query<Entity>()
           .Fetch(x=>x.Photos.First())//
           .Fetch(x=>x.Features)
           .ToList();
```

or

```
List<Entity> data = session.Query<Entity>()
               .Fetch(x=>x.Photos.FirstOrDefault())//
               .Fetch(x=>x.Features)
               .ToList();
```

aslo read this before using this methods : [When to use .First and when to use .FirstOrDefault with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Entity> data = session.Query<Entity>()
          .Fetch(x=>x.Photos.FirstOrDefualt())//here I need only first element
          .Fetch(x=>x.Features)
          .ToList();
```