# System.InvalidCastException. OK... Where?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I'm really having trouble using Linq on a SortedList. I have a Class Library and a Test WinForms app. The class library code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JTS
{
    public static class Pictures
    {
        public static class PictureManagement
        {
            public static SortedList<int, Picture> PictureList = new SortedList<int, Picture>();

            public static class Acquire
            {
                public static Picture ById(int id)
                {
                    Picture picture = null;

                    if(PictureList != null)
                    {
                        picture = (Picture)from pic in PictureList
                                          where
                                              pic.Key == id
                                          select (pic.Value as Picture);
                    }
                    return picture;
                }
            }
        }

        public class Picture : PictureBox
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public class PictureProperties
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Extension { get; set; }
                public string OriginalPath { get; set; }
                public Image OriginalPhoto { get; set; }
                public string Credits { get; set; }

                public Size DesignTimeSize { get; set; }
                public Point DesignTimeLocation { get; set; }

            }

            public PictureProperties Properties { get; set; }

            public class PictureThumbnail
            {
                public string Name { get { return "T" + Name; } }
                public Size Size { get; set; }
            }

            public PictureThumbnail Thumbnail { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Test winforms app code is:

```
using JTS;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void test()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                JTS.Pictures.PictureManagement.PictureList.Add(i, new JTS.Pictures.Picture()
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Properties = new JTS.Pictures.Picture.PictureProperties()
                        {
                            Name = "Travis",
                            Credits = "people in here"
                        },

                        Thumbnail = new JTS.Pictures.Picture.PictureThumbnail()
                        {
                            Size = new Size(250, 250)
                        }
                    });

                Console.WriteLine("pics added to list");

                Console.WriteLine("getting Picture by id 3");

                JTS.Pictures.Picture pic = JTS.Pictures.PictureManagement.Acquire.ById(3);

                Console.WriteLine(pic.Id);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test();
        }
    }
}
```

If you're going to paste this into VS, don't forget to Add `System.Windows.Forms` as a Reference to the class library.

The problem I'm having is when I run the Test winforms application, on FormLoad, I get an exception, which says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in JTS.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,JTS.Pictures+Picture],JTS.Pictures+Picture]'
>   to type 'Picture'.

Now, I know what an invalid cast is. But I don't know what it's referring to. Where have I made an invalid cast?

Comment: Nit: `JTS.Pictures.PictureManagement.Acquire.ById(3);` probably shouldn't be *in* the loop..

Comment: @user2864740 yep, thanks for picking that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the error message, the error is here:

```
picture = (Picture)from pic in PictureList
                               where  pic.Key == id
                               select (pic.Value as Picture);
```

Try this:

```
picture = from pic in PictureList
                      where  pic.Key == id
                      select (pic.Value as Picture)).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Or, since it is a `SortedList`, why not simply use this?**

```
var picture = PictureList[id];
```

Comment: Anytime mate. Just to add in a lil more - [First() vs FirstOrDefault()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1024577/1182982)

Comment: @Yasser: Edited it just a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHofman much appreciated. I'll be using `...PictureList[id]` for this from now on. But at-least I know for future reference how to do something like this with Linq.

Answer (score 2):

```
picture = (Picture)from pic in PictureList
                                          where
                                              pic.Key == id
                                          select (pic.Value as Picture);
```

This query returns `IEnumerable<Picture>`, not `Picture`.

Try this:

```
picture = (Picture)from pic in PictureList
                                          where
                                              pic.Key == id
                                          select (pic.Value as Picture).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

This query returns an `IEnumerable<T>` after get executed:

```
from pic in PictureList
where pic.Key == id
select (pic.Value as Picture)
```

You can't cast it to single `Picture`, if you want to get a single item, use `First` or `Single` method.

```
(from pic in PictureList
where pic.Key == id
select (pic.Value as Picture)).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Lambda:

```
Picture picture = PictureList.Where(pic => pic.Key == id).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

This code replace the part where you doing a select from the PictureList collection. The problem with your code is that the `where` clause returns a collection of `Picture` and you're assigning the collection to a `Picture` which is not a collection, hence you're getting an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: What is the intent of this snippet? Should it be added or replaced? Where should it go? Why does it fix the problem?

Comment: This code replace the part where you doing a select from the PictureList collection. The problem with your code is that the "Where" clause return a collection of Pictures and you're assigning the collection to a Picture which is not a collection hence you're getting an InvalidCastException.