# from sql to div with linq asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to retrieve information from ms sql server to my div.

```
<div id="blablablaText" runat="server">
                    ...
                </div>
```

and here's my source code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (myDbDataContext wdb = new myDbDataContext ())
        {
            Article ar = new Article();

            var a = from p in wdb.Articles
                    where p.Id == 16
                    select p.Text;



            blablablaText.InnerText = a.ToString();
        }
    }
```

after that my output is:

> SELECT [t0].[Text] FROM [dbo].[Article] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try a.First() instead of a.ToString().

Comment: @George First() is not the right way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to execute `.First()` on that instead of `.ToString()`;

`a` is a query. `First()` will execute it and return the value of first row of the executed sql select statement. As you selected only one string column `a` will already be the string you want.

Beware. First() must find at least one row or it will throw an exception. If you want to get `null` in the worst case scenario then you should use `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to to get the first or firstordefault before converting to string

```
using (myDbDataContext wdb = new myDbDataContext ())
        {
            Article ar = new Article();

            var a = from p in wdb.Articles
                    where p.Id == 16
                    select p.Text;



            blablablaText.InnerText = a.First().ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (myDbDataContext wdb = new myDbDataContext ())
    {
        Article ar = new Article();

        var a = (from p in wdb.Articles
                where p.Id == 16
                select p.Text).FirstorDefault();



        blablablaText.InnerText = a.ToString();
    }
```

Your should be using `FirstorDefault()` instead of `First();` as If there is nothing in your variable a then `First` will throw an exception where as `FirstorDefault` will set it to null/empty.

[First VS FirstorDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq)