# Difference between First, FirstOrDefault and singleOrDefault keywords in ORM

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, orm, telerik

eI need to select a particular single data element from first row ordered descending by date.  Please specify the differences between the following keywords.

- First
- FirstOrDefault
- singleOrDefault

Also need the precedence/order and usage rules of placing Orderby, where & select in Linq ORM Query. It would be much helpful if answer could be clear & descriptive.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google gives you the following Questions which address your question:

- [When to use .First and when to use .FirstOrDefault with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq)
- [LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

You might also find the following article useful as it goes into each method:

- http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/

As stated in the answers, the names do give it away (to those familiar), but here's a quick overview:

**First**

Will return the first entry in a collection (one or more results returned), will throw an exception if no records returned.

**FirstOrDefault**

Will return the first entry in a collection (one or more results returned), will return the appropriate default object if no records returned

**SingleOrDefault**

This one isn't really the same as the previously mentioned functions, it will return the result only if only one record is returned, otherwise will return the appropriate default object.

I tend to use `First` if I know that my results will *always* return "something", I use `FirstOrDefault` when I just want the first element but know that sometimes the query might return nothing. I've yet to personally use `SingleOrDefault` but it should only be used where your query is only ever going to return one row and that returned results should be ignored if more than one result exists.