# Cannot use Text property from a manually created TextBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I can not display the `Text` property of a `TextBox` that I created using code. I created the textbox using `TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox()` but `MessageBox(newTextBox.Text)` gives error.

Here is the code I talked about:

```
var name = String.Format("R{0}C{1}B{2}", row, column, box); 
TextBox newTextBox = (TextBox)Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault();      
MessageBox.Show(newTextBox.Text);
```

P.S. I have textbox that are name `R1C1B1`, `R1C2B1`` and so on!

---

Error Message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SudokuSolver.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Cannot read text from a manually created TextBox control" - does it throw an exception or shows empty string? And it is better to use `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq in your case, because if `Find` fails - the `newTextBox` will be null.

Comment: Your code is correct.Make sure that the textbox is on the form and not inside another container (like a panel)

Comment: From where you you run the code? Have you tried it from a Button?

Comment: I do run it from a button and the textboxes are on the form

Comment: did my solution solve your problem? if it solved please mark my solution as answer so that others could benefit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `Textbox` is actually within some other containers, like a `Panel`.

Try to find your control using a recursive approach:

```
public static Control FindTargetTextbox(Control control, string targetName)
{
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        if (child is TextBox && child.Name == targetName)
        {
            return child;
        }
    }

    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        Control target = FindTargetComponent(child);

        if (target != null)
        {
            return target;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Bear in mind that your form is the biggest container, therefore you should pass it in as the starting point:

```
TextBox textBox = FindTargetTextbox(this, name);
```

**Edit**
As @mikeng mentioned in the comment, we are able to merge two `foreach` into one like this:

```
public static Control FindTargetTextbox(Control control, string targetName)
{
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        if (child is TextBox && child.Name == targetName)
        {
            return child;
        }

        Control target = FindTargetComponent(child);

        if (target != null)
        {
            return target;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is indeed another valid approach, but one should choose the most appropriate approach based on the real situation:

The first approach explores **all controls in the same container** before it goes deep into a child control of that container, which is a **Breadth First Search**, while the second approach focuses on **nested controls one by one**, i.e. it goes to next container only after it finishes processing all controls in the current container, which is a **Depth First Search**.

Comment: Nice recursive method, but why not merge the two foreach statements into one ?

Comment: @mikeng it's just another implementation. if you merge them up, you will need to go to the deepest of a container then another, but split them will exam all controls inside 1 container, then go deep.

Answer (score 0):

As i said your is correct so

1)The isn't a textbox with the specified name
2)There is a textbox but it is inside a container

In any case,use this code to find which controls exist on your form and then call the Find method from the correct container

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
            if (item is TextBox)
                Console.WriteLine("TextBox:" + item.Name);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().Name + ":" + item.Name);
```

}