# How to check record exists in group by subquery in linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to get the result of which records exist in a group by records in Linq. 
I have got the query in SQL but am struggling to get it in LINQ

**In SQL query**

```
 select LEVEL, DESCR
   from ACTIVITY_LKUP 
   WHERE LEVEL IN ( //Checking row exists
    select TOP 2 b.LEVEL
    from ACTIVITY_LKUP b
    WHERE b.LEVEL > (
    select max(b.LEVEL)
    from ACTIVITY a, ACTIVITY_LKUP b
    WHERE b.TYPE = a.ACTIVITY_TYPE
    and a.JOB_CANDIDATE_ID = 1
   )
  group by b.level //Grouping here
  )
order by LEVEL
```

**In Linq query**

```
 var duplicate =(from lkup in ACTIVITY_LKUP
                where lkup.LEVEL== (from actlk in ACTIVITY_LKUP //Iam Not able to check row exists in  the group by
                where actlk.LEVEL >
                (
                 from act in ACTIVITY
                 join lkup in ACTIVITY_LKUP on act.ACTIVITY_TYPE equals lkup.TYPE
                 where act.JOB_CANDIDATE_ID == 1
                 orderby lkup.LEVEL
                 select lkup.LEVEL
                 ).First()            
                group actlk by actlk.LEVEL into lggrp
                select new { LEVEL = lggrp.Key,DESCR=lggrp.Select(x=>x.DESCR)              
              }).Take(2)
             select lkup)
```

Showing error line "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable".

How can we do it in LINQ? Help me anyone.

Comment: It looks like lkup.LEVEL is an 'int?' or Nullable<int> whereas the value return for comparison is a collection or 'IQueryable<int>' Which makes sense when you are using .'Take(2)' which in this case would return an IQueryable<T> with a length of 2. You could try changing Take(2) to .FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq) is a good question that describes the difference between the return of First()/FirstOrDefault() and Take(int).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try joining equal columns within the query, like

```
var duplicate=(from lg in reslandentity.ACTIVITY_LKUP
               join grp in
                  (from actlk in reslandentity.ACTIVITY_LKUP
                    where actlk.LEVEL >
                     (
                       from act in reslandentity.ACTIVITY
                       join lkup in reslandentity.ACTIVITY_LKUP on act.ACTIVITY_TYPE equals lkup.TYPE
                       where act.JOB_CANDIDATE_ID == 1
                       orderby lkup.LEVEL
                       select lkup.LEVEL
                     ).FirstOrDefault()
                      orderby actlk.LEVEL
                      group actlk by actlk.LEVEL into lggrp
                      select new { LEVEL = lggrp.Key }).Take(2) 
                 on lg.LEVEL equals grp.LEVEL
                 select lg).ToList();
```

Hope it helps you..!!