# How to remove a word that already exist in errorList

Tags: c#, mvvm, hunspell, spelling

I have a method that runs spellcheck in a word, but what i want here is that if the word already exist in my errorlist it should not be add as error. below is my code.

```
public void CheckSpelling()
    {
        int lineno = 0;
        bool start = false;
        foreach (string line in _contentList)
        {
            lineno++;
            if (line.Contains("<text>"))
            {
                start = true;
            }
            if (start)
            {
                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "<.*?>[^<]+</(.*?)>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    List<string> customdiclist = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["customdic"])));
                    string[] strArray = Regex.Replace(match.Value, "</?[^>]+>", string.Empty).Split(' ');
                    foreach (string word in strArray)
                    {
                        if ((word.Trim() != string.Empty) && ((word.Substring(0, 1) != word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()) && !_helper.CheckSpelling(Regex.Match(word, "[a-zA-Z]+").Value) && !customdiclist.Contains(word)))
                        {
                            ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel()
                            {
                                LineNumber = lineno,
                                ErrorMessage = "Please Check Misspelled words",
                                Text = word
                            };
                            ErrorList.Add(errorModel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

_helper.CheckSpelling

```
class Helper
    {        
        private static readonly string DictPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dictionary"]);

        private readonly Hunspell _splCheck = new Hunspell(DictPath + @"\nl_NL.aff", DictPath + @"\nl_NL.dic");
        public bool CheckSpelling(string strWord)
        {
            if(!_splCheck.Spell(strWord.Trim()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Can some one help, I dont want any duplicate word in my errorlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to check if your `ErrorList` already contains an `ErrorModel` object with a `Text` property which has the value of the `word` you are checking.

Using `FirstOrDefault` you can check to see if it returns a null. If an item cannot be found in the list, a null will be returned as the default value because your list is a collection of class objects (whose default value is null).

If the `FirstOrDefault` returns null then the `word` has not been added to the `ErrorList`.

For more information see [When to use .First and when to use .FirstOrDefault with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq).

```
foreach (string word in strArray)
{
    if ((word.Trim() != string.Empty) && ((word.Substring(0, 1) != word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()) && !_helper.CheckSpelling(Regex.Match(word, "[a-zA-Z]+").Value) && !customdiclist.Contains(word)))
    {
        if (ErrorList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Text == word) == null)
        {
            ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel()
            {
                LineNumber = lineno,
                ErrorMessage = "Please Check Misspelled words",
                Text = word
            };
            ErrorList.Add(errorModel);
        }
    }
}
```