# ASP.NET Entity framework Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a line of code like so:

```
ProjectClass pricing = db.Data.Where(model => model.collection == “aaa”);
```

but I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ProjectName.Models.ProjectClass>' to 'ProjectName.Models.ProjectClass'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Here is my ProjectClass

```
public class ProjectClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Design")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Price")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n0}")]
        public int basePrice { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Size")]
        public int sqft { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Collection")]
        public string collection { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Hidden")]
        public bool hidden { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Querys for results with any quantity of results use `Where`**

```
 List<ProjectClass> result = db.Data.Where(model => model.collection == “aaa”).ToList();
```

**Querys for only 0 or 1 result use `SingleOrDefault`**

```
 var result = db.data.SingleOrDefault(model => model.collection == "aaa");
```

The result will be `null` if no record matched.

**For querying the first matching record use `FirstOrDefault`**

```
var result = db.data.FirstOrDefault(model => model.collection == "aaa");
```

The result will be `null` if no record matched.

Answer (score 1):

Select only one item:

```
ProjectClass pricing = db.Data.Where(model => model.collection == “aaa”).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: would that give me all the results where collection would = aaa or just one row?

Comment: It will give you first item which match condition. If any element doesn't match condition result will be null. See about FirstOrDefault() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx  Adn you can see differences from First() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq

Answer (score 1):

```
ProjectClass pricing = db.Data.FirstOrDefault(model => model.collection == "aaa");
```

Currently you are selecting a list. The above will get the first item. If you are expecting exactly one you can do SingleOrDefault instead.

If you want a collection (list) then materialize the result using ToList or ToArray (*there are more but these are the common ones*).

```
List<ProjectClass> pricing = db.Data.Where(model => model.collection == "aaa").ToList();
```

Comment: but I am looking for all items

Answer (score 0):

```
ProjectClass pricing = db.Data.Where(model => model.collection == “aaa”);
```

Above code is wrong because [Where()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) will return filtered sequence based on predicate. So, result is MANY not SINGLE element! Even if your condition inside Where() is applicable to SINGLE element result will NEVER be single element.

Exception is thrown because **pricing** variable is declared as single ProjectClass.

If you are not sure which type you expecting as result you can use:

```
var pricing = db.Data.Where(model => model.collection == “aaa”);
```