# Linq expression crashes when it doesn't find what I'm looking for

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If i = {1,2} no problem.

If iId = 3 (or anything else) why does .First() crash.

```
public class C { public int ID, public string nam }
int i = 3;
C c = new List<C>;
c.Add(new C{ID = 1, nam="hello" });
c.Add(new C{ID = 2, nam=world" });
C r = c.First(e => e.ID.Equals(i));
```

The exception is:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>
> Sequence contains no matching element

I would think the least the expression would have to do is return null.
Instead it crashed.
That makes no sense to me.
A returned null would make sense to me.

What do you do to work around this?  What is your best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to agree .First() could be a little more frendly but you get what you want by using .FirstOrDefault()

[When to use .First and when to use .FirstOrDefault with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Change from `First(e => e.ID.Equals(i))` to `FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID.Equals(i))`, then you'll get nulls (since `default(C)` is null, as that is the default for a reference type) which you can handle how you see fit, rather than having your app crash.

Here's the MDSN link to `FirstOrDefault`, if you need any more info/examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx