# How to check the result length of where

Tags: c#

```
 List<object> _list = new List<object>();

 public object Get => _list.Where( x => x.GetType() == typeof( int ) ).First();
```

Using the above code will cause a `System.InvalidOperationException` when the length of `Where` is zero.

```
 public object Get2
 {
     get
     {
         var where = _list.Where( x => x.GetType() == typeof( int ) );
         if( 0 < where.Count() )
         {
             return where.First();
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
```

So I am using it to fix this, but is there a way to make the code cleaner?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Does the list need to hold object?

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault()`  instead of `First()`. Because, `First()` returns First Element Of Sequence and it returns First Element Of Sequence.`FirstOrDefault ()` does not throws Exception when There IS No element Present in Table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FirstOrDefault will be the thing that you are looking for:

```
public object Get => _list.FirstOrDefault( x => x.GetType() == typeof(int))
```

As you faced the `First()` raise `NullReferenceException` if the collection is `null` where as the `FirstOrDefault` will give you the default value in case there is nothing to select.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq) you can find threads that compare `.First` and `FirstOrDefault` and describe the scenarios where you need to use them

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lim: Happy to help you always!

Answer (score 4):

Use `FirstOrDefault` to get `null` as return value, when nothing got matched.

```
public object Get => _list.FirstOrDefault( x => x.GetType() == typeof( int ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `First()`

```
 public object Get => _list.Where( x => x.GetType() == typeof( int ) ).First();
```

Use `FirstOrDefault()`

```
public object Get => _list.Where( x => x.GetType() == typeof( int ) ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`. Because, `First()` returns first element of sequence and it returns first element of sequence. `FirstOrDefault ()` does not throws exception when There is no element present in table.

```
public object Get => _list.Where( x => x.GetType() == typeof( int ) ).FirstOrDefault ();
```

Answer (score 0):

FirstOrDefault: Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found. Throws exception: Only if the source is null. Use when: When more than 1 element is expected and you want only the first.