# I want to find the column index using Column data

Tags: c#, worksheet

I'm trying to get the column index using the column name, but if I enter a column name which is not in the dataset then I get an exception. How do I handle this?

```
string columnName ="ABC";

int ColumnNumber-0;

if(ws.Cells["1:1"].First(c => c.Value.ToString() == columnName ).Start.Column!=Undefined)
{
    ColumnNumber=ws.Cells["1:1"].First(c => c.Value.ToString() == columnName ).Start.Column;
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception do you get ?

Comment: _Some exception_?? Really, that is not a helpful problem description. And how would you expect to find a column from contetn to be reliable in the first place?? Also: Please post only real code, i.e. code without typos!

Comment: Have a feeling this is VBA and not C#.

Depending on the exception of course, I think there is three possible problems you have.

Comment: "Sequence contains no matching element"...This is the exception i'm getting

Comment: Instead of using `First` you should use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559) (or check beforehand with `Any`).

Comment: Thank You  - Elaskanator . Any function is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely candidate for the exception is your call to First. It is not finding any items that match Value == columnName and throwing an exception. I would suggest breaking up your if statement so you can handle this case. I would also suggest using FirstOrDefault instead since it will just return null instead of throwing an exception.

```
var myCell = ws.Cells["1:1"].FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value.ToString() == columnName );
if (myCell != null && myCell.Start.Column != Undefined)
{
    ColumnNumber = myCell.Start.Column;
}
```