# C# linq lambda expression group by multiple columns and get the first items of group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

This is how my table data looks like ,

```
   Id          C1            C2             C3 
 -------------------------------------------------
   1           John          1990           A
   2           John          1990           B
   3           John          2000           C
   4           Mary          2001           D
   5           Mary          2010           E 
   6           Mary          2010           F
   7           Jack          2010           G
   8           Jack          2010           H
   9           Jack          2011           I
```

What I want to do is I want to group by C1,C2 columns and get the first items of each group which is order by `C3` column descending.
So the result will be like

```
      Id          C1            C2             C3 
     -------------------------------------------------
       1           John          1990           B
       3           John          2000           C
       4           Mary          2001           D
       5           Mary          2010           F 
       7           Jack          2010           H
       9           Jack          2011           I
```

And I also want to filter row number 2 to 5 using `skip` and `take` function.
So the **Final** result should be like

```
          Id          C1            C2             C3 
         -------------------------------------------------
           3           John          2000           C
           4           Mary          2001           D
           5           Mary          2010           F 
           7           Jack          2010           H
```

What I have tried is

```
await data.GroupBy(d => new { d.C1, d.C2 }).Skip(1).Take(4).FirstAsync();
```

But it only retrun **one** row.
How can I solve for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `Select` and since there will be multiple results you'd need to use `ToListAsync` instead.

```
data.GroupBy(d => new { d.C1, d.C2 })
   .Select(grp => grp.First())
   .Skip(1)
   .Take(4)
   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `first()` and `firstOrDefault()` , which is better ?

Comment: @StevenSann In this case either will work, but it's safe to use `First` since the resulting groups from a `GroupBy` can not be empty.

Comment: is `.Select(grp => grp.First())` will randomly retrun a row of group ? can I order and get the first row ? for ( eg. in my question , I want to order by `C3` column descending. so the first row should be ` 2           John          1990           B`

Comment: @StevenSan In that case you can co `grp => grp.OrderBy(x => x.C3).First()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by,

```
using System; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
...

var result = await data.GroupBy(d => new { d.C1, d.C2 }) //Group by C1 and C2
                 .Select(s => s.First())  //Select first record from each Group
                 .Skip(1)     //Skip first record
                 .Take(4)     //Pick up next 4 records
                 .ToListAsync()    //Convert 4 records to List.
```

Comment: `first()` and `firstOrDefault()` , which is better ?

Comment: @StevenSann `FirstOrDefault` isn't needed since `GroupBy` will always return a collection of items that do not have empty sets.

Comment: @juharr, thanks for the information. I was not aware of this fact. I updated my answer with `First()`

Comment: @StevenSann, You can use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`. for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar , is .Select(grp => grp.First()) will randomly retrun a row of group ? can I order and get the first row ? for ( eg. in my question , I want to order by C3 column descending. so the first row should be ` 2 John 1990 B`