# How to create a function to check if a record exists with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and Entity Framework Core 8 against a SQL Server 2022

```
private bool IsItemExist(Guid optionVisibleBusinessId)
{
    BusinessTypeHiddenOption businessTypeHiddenOption =
            _db.BusinessTypeHiddenOptions.First(x => x.OptionVisibleBusinessId == optionVisibleBusinessId);

    if (businessTypeHiddenOption != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

How to check if a record exists in this situation?

Comment: using `First`  expect that there is at least one record... so rider thinks correctly. use `FirstOrDefault` is you aren't sure

Comment: See also 'When to use First and when to use FirstOrDefault':  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq

Comment: If you are using .First, if there's any record, it would return the first one it finds. If no record it would throw an exception instead of null value. In your situation I think it's best to use .Any. Any would return bool (true/false) if it finds any value that matches the condition. Usage: bool exist = _db.BusinessTypeHiddenOptions.Any(x => x.OptionVisibleBusinessId == optionVisibleBusinessId);

Answer (score 2):

```
private bool ItemExists(Guid optionVisibleBusinessId)
{
    return _db.BusinessTypeHiddenOptions.Any(x => x.OptionVisibleBusinessId == optionVisibleBusinessId);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using `FirstOrDefault()` will execute a query returning the entire entity which EF will materialize and track when it is completely unnecessary. `.Any()` will execute an `EXISTS` statement to return a True or False result.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because you are returning `First` which always returns something (or throws an exception).  You likely intended `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Seemly, It require change method mask to Task<bool> . I tried all above solution, It did not work.